# How to convert string of numbers enclosed in parenthesis to a tuple by removing the double inverted comas?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, netlogo

I am new to python... I am using Python from Netlogo. I have an output that looks like this:

> ["('251','122','501')", "('288','3','506')", "('329','5','505')", "('390','3','501')", "('461','140','501')"]

I have been struggling to get rid of the double quotes... I have tried using `replace()`, and `strip()` but nothing works.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using.

Comment: you can use `eval` to evaluate those strings and convert them into tuples. do something like `[eval(i) for i in myList]` where `myList` is the one you posted. This will give as result a list of tuples `[('251', '122', '501'), ('288', '3', '506'), ('329', '5', '505'), ('390', '3', '501'), ('461', '140', '501')]`

Comment: Please be clear about what the output should look like

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use `ast.literal_eval`, or even just `eval`:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> T = ["('251','122','501')", "('288','3','506')"]
>>> [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in T]
[('251', '122', '501'), ('288', '3', '506')]
```

See also: [`eval` vs. `ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Comment: Thank you so much! using ast.literal_eval worked!

Comment: no problem! glad that you found it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

the issue here is that your original data structure is a list of strings, that happen to look like `python` tuples. the double quotes here are a way for python to tell you the datatype is a string.

there is no difference in type between this: `["string1", "string2", "string3"]` and what you have

so what we have to do is write code to translate the strings into what we want. this should work:

```
def tupefy(some_string=None) -> tuple:
    return (int(some_string[1:-1].split()[0][1:-1]),
            int(some_string[1:-1].split()[1][1:-1]),
            int(some_string[1:-1].split()[2][1:-1]))

my_list = [tupefy(item) for item in my_list]
```

obviously this isn't perfect, it doesn't account for strings that are a different format or tuples that contain things other than numeric values, but I hope it's a good start for you